# How do I track GPS signal from a GPS Module

Tags: ios, swift, gps, swift4, swift5

It might be a stupid question, but I have no idea where to start.
I have a GPS device and I want to build an app in swift that will be able to track this particular device. I've seen so many small trackers that have apps for iOS but I want to build my own. Any help or a resource to get me started would be much appreciated. 
I hope I am not offtopic!